# Read a float binary file into a 2D array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, binaryfiles

Now I have a binary file contains float data, each data is 4 bytes, I want to read it into a 2D array, when I use the

```
B1 = np.fromfile('/home/lijiao/Documents/transform/Data/AHI8_OBI_1000M_NOM_20160812_0040.hdf_B1.dat', dtype=float)
```

It will give me a 1D array of length 60500000, so how to read the data by each 4 bytes?

Edit:
This is my solution:

```
filename = '/home/lijiao/Documents/transform/Data/AHI8_OBI_1000M_NOM_20160812_0040.hdf_B1.dat'

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
data = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.float32)
array = np.reshape(data, [11000, 11000])
```

Comment: If each value is 4 bytes, you should use `dtype=np.float32`.  You'll have to reshape the array to make it 2D.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works!